# how to keep same padding for both flex box content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

tried to keep same gap between both flex box contents whenever i swap contents in 2nd row. How to keep same to same padding after swapping 2nd flex box contents.

here i attach my problem picture

[image: flex-box padding problem]

Here is my html code

```css
.profile-container {
  width: 80%;
}

.profile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.profile img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="profile-pic">
      <img src="avater.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro voluptas sapiente laudantium expedita similique cum enim voluptates modi mollitia, animi architecto adipisci reiciendis beatae dicta non dolorum blanditiis odit veniam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="profile">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro voluptas sapiente laudantium expedita similique cum enim voluptates modi mollitia, animi architecto adipisci reiciendis beatae dicta non dolorum blanditiis odit veniam?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-pic">
      <img src="avater.png" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a specific width for your image, prevent shrinking and growing with `flex: 0 0 [width]` and a max width for your text. Then you set `justify-content:space-between` on your profile element to distribute the remaining space between your text and the picture.

Your CSS would look like this (adjust with the width of your liking):

```
.profile-container {
  width: 80%;
}
.profile { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.profile .text {
  max-width: calc(100% - 115px); /* 100% minus width superior to width of image */
}
.profile img {
  width: 55px;
  flex: 0 0 55px;
}
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/hcj183pk/